Hollowtech II road crankset on mtb
I have an old mtb that I would like to convert for road use.  The BB shell is 68mm, so I was thinking of using a Shimano 105 triple (50-39-30).  Then I would use an Ultegra BB (BBR60).  Would this work?  It is a road crankset and road BB (Hollowtech II) on a 68mm BB shell.  When I read of people having issues, it seems when they use road crankset with a mtb BB.  Just thought I would ask the experts.

Well currently there is a triple (28-38-48) so I think the 30-39-50 will fit.  I read that there are folks that have trouble installing a road crank on the mtb.  I am just wondering if the spindle of a road crank is the same size as the spindle of mtb cranks?  I think I read that the BB cups are different size between road and mtb's.  So not sure if the problems people have is that they were using mtb BB's with a road crank-set?

Just an opinion, but I doubt that a 50/39/30 will make a significant difference over a 48/38/28, it's only a 4% difference on top speeds, where aero drag prevails, and where a converted MTB will be at disadvantage compared to a road bike anyway (that you can probably mitigate by spinning, which negates the point of having a faster top gear...).

Assuming a 29er with 47 tires and an 11-tooth small cog, spinning at 90 rpm as @Rеnаud suggests gets you all the way to 50 kph/30 mph per https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gear-calc.html.  How hard is that?  Per http://bikecalculator.com/wattsMetric.html, sustaining 50 kph on a MTB requires 776W.  That's about twice the max power level that Tour de France champions can sustain.

I agree with the reasoning presented.  My thoughts to make the change is that this is a 6-speed and would like to go 10-speed.  I am not sure if just spreading the rear triangle and installing a 10-speed cassette along with the shifters is all that needs to be done.  A 10-speed chain is thinner thus new chain-rings is in order.  Besides I have 10-speed shifters just sitting in a box waiting to be used, not to mention the itch to play with the bike in terms of mechanical changes.

I forgot to mention that if I could switch to a 10-speed, I would go from a 14-28 6-speed cassette to a 11-28 10-speed and I think that will be a 25% increase with a 50-39-30 chain rings.  My calculations may be off.

@msg Indeed, it's a significant upgrade, that requires to change the chainring anyway - and also probably the rear wheel. That being said (and it's also an opinion), if you need to replace everything, 2x gravel components are a better match for a MTB conversion than 3x road components - for example Microshift Sword - with Advent X shifters if you want to stay in flat bars. Maintaining a 3x is worth doing, but I don't think that it's worth spending money on a 3x upgrade. If you need the range, a 2x with a wide range cassette is a better combination IMHO.

Renaud,  very good point and thoughts that I have gone over.  The reality is that it just makes more sense to purchase a bike and use it as intended than to modify a mtb so that it is mostly useful.  What I want to do means changing all but the frame, brakes, seat post and saddle.  To change everything would probably cost more than a new appropriate bike.  But having the bike and shifters on hand, and having time to do the work draws me into this dilemma.  You speak wisely and I’m not convinced to make the change but to just get something designed for what I intend to do.

It's a question of clearance with the chainstays. There are many mountain bikes that won't have anywhere near the chainring clearance you need for any one of those rings in their respective positions. The 50 is the likely culprit. If you're talking old enough, i.e. back in the days of extremely long chainstays, that can be different. Even if the all the rings clear, the next problem is crank clearance.
It's not a hard no and if it's steel, in some cases you can dimple your way out of it if you're willing to modify the frame.

Are you sure clearance between the outermost chainring and the chainstays is ever an issue? I'm having a hard time imagining it, considering how far outboard it is located in a triple. In a double it would be plausible enough.

@leftaroundabout some mtb chainstays go straight back just wide enough for a tyre, until just past the largest expected chainring, then suddenly get wider, going almost straight back again wide enough for a hub

While it doesn't strictly answer the question, another option is to look at trekking cranksets (that has been discontinued recently, but it still possible to have the parts) — they require MTB bottom brackets, so on a 68mm shell, you'll need 2 additional spacers (total of 3 with shimano BBs).
They are available with combinations like 48/36/26, which is not so far off from the 105, but the chainline is 50mm (vs 45mm), that can be enough of a difference for frame clearance issues.
EDIT: on the spindle length between road and MTB, I made some measurements that I reported on this answer. The difference is 5.5mm, so it's likely that indeed the problems are linked to using a road crank with a MTB shell/BB.

Thanks for the info, very useful.  Thanks for sharing the measurements you made of the spindle lengths.  Also here is a link that compares the mtb vs road BB:  https://www.tobiasfeltus.com/blog/the-burning-question-can-i-use-a-shimano-road-bottom-bracket-on-a-mtb/

To complete this, the road triple sets use about 2.5mm spacers each side of the bottom bracket on the spindle (which is longer than for double). This would allow use on a 73mm bottom bracket shell if road bearing cups were used and the spindle spacers, left and right, removed. It is not applicable information for @msg as the shell in question is 68mm. But there is alot of scope for crossing over road parts
